# apache + nginx as proxy testing

Tags: apache, nginx, ubuntu-server, web-development-server

I want to know how to test if nginx is working properly as proxy
My system is ubuntu-server
I want to know if nginx really takes all the static data and apache doesn't, because sometimes people say, that apache can also operate static data in conjunction with nginx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
wget --server-response --spider --recursive --level=1 --accept=png,css,js \
  http://host/ 2>&1 | grep -P "^(  Server|--)"
```

The output looks like this:

```
--2015-01-27 14:23:34--  http://wiki.nginx.org/Main
  Server: nginx/1.5.12
--2015-01-27 14:23:36--  http://wiki.nginx.org/robots.txt
  Server: nginx/1.5.12
--2015-01-27 14:23:37--  http://wiki.nginx.org/local/nginx-logo.png
  Server: nginx/1.5.12
--2015-01-27 14:23:37--  http://wiki.nginx.org/local/install.png
  Server: nginx/1.5.12
--2015-01-27 14:23:37--  http://wiki.nginx.org/local/modules.png
  Server: nginx/1.5.12
--2015-01-27 14:23:38--  http://wiki.nginx.org/local/addons.png
  Server: nginx/1.5.12
--2015-01-27 14:23:38--  http://wiki.nginx.org/local/configure.png
  Server: nginx/1.5.12
--2015-01-27 14:23:38--  http://wiki.nginx.org/local/community.png
```